# SharePoint online show/hide column - make show or hide columns mandate

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm looking for SharePoint online show/hide columns code, below code is working for me but my requirement is to make hide column mandate based on the selection. if i make the column as required field in the sharepoint list settings, unable to save the form with adding text to the column even though it was hidden. i have multiple columns based on one selection so i need all the columns to make as mandate. please help

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function () {
            $('nobr:contains("Col1")').closest('tr').hide();
            $("select[title='Opportunity']").change(function () {
            console.log("selection changed", $("[title='Opportunity'] option:selected").text());
                if ($("[title='Opportunity'] option:selected").text() != "Proposal") {
                    $('nobr:contains("Col1")').closest('tr').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $('nobr:contains("Col1")').closest('tr').show();
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value for required field when Col1 not equal to Proposal so that it will avoid required validation in List form:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function () {
            $('nobr:contains("Title")').closest('tr').hide();
            $("select[title='Opportunity']").change(function () {
            console.log("selection changed", $("[title='Opportunity'] option:selected").text());
                if ($("[title='Opportunity'] option:selected").text() != "Proposal") {
                    $('nobr:contains("Title")').closest('tr').hide();
                    $("input[title='Title Required Field']").val("Required");
                }
                else {
                    $('nobr:contains("Title")').closest('tr').show();
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick revert, but to be frank i have many fields to pop up based on the proposal selected value. in the sameway in the additional fields based on another dropdown selected value few more to become mandate. is it possible to accommodate in Validation settings? I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: @yrameshgupta, yes using validation settings, could also check about required data column, you could see a sample from here:

https://info.summit7systems.com/blog/how-to-conditionally-require-data-in-sharepoint-columns

Comment: Thanks Jerry. Will give a try and update on the progress.

Comment: Oops missed to update you, i have additional fields based on drop down selection value as proposal. those additional fields also contain Person or Group column. these are not available for Validation settings. Do we have any alternative solution for this. Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: Yes, actually, Person field can't be used in formula. Another option if you can do validation using PreSaveAction https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0114e579-a5da-4100-a1ca-ebf5ec78432f/validate-two-people-picker-fields-in-presaveaction?forum=sharepointdevelopment